Server authoritative movement + client prediction issue using Fishnet in Unity 6
So my problem is that I implemented a server authoritative movement using a Navmesh Agent in Unity and I tried to implement client side prediction using the Networking framework Fishnet. The problem that I have is that everything works fine on the server so the data is replicating, but nothing is happening on the client... Here is my player controller:
using FishNet.Object;
using FishNet.Object.Prediction;
using FishNet.Transporting;
using Unity.Cinemachine;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

[RequireComponent (typeof(NavMeshAgent))]
public class PlayerController : NetworkBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private InputActionAsset InputActions;
    private InputActionMap PlayerActionMap;
    private InputAction Movement;

    [SerializeField]
    private Animator Animator;

    [SerializeField]
    private Camera Camera;
    [SerializeField]
    private CinemachineCamera CinemachineCamera;

    [SerializeField]
    private NavMeshAgent Agent;
    [SerializeField]
    [Range(0f, 0.99f)]
    private float Smoothing = 0.25f;
    [SerializeField]
    private float TargetLerpSpeed = 1;

    private float LerpTime = 0;
    private Vector3 LastDirection;
    private Vector3 TargetDirection;

    public override void OnStartNetwork()
    {
        Agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();

        TimeManager.OnTick += TimeManager_OnTick;
    }

    public override void OnStartClient()
    {
        if (!IsOwner) return;

        Camera = Camera.main;
        CinemachineCamera = GameObject.Find("VirtualCamera").GetComponent<CinemachineCamera>();
        //CinemachineCamera.Target.TrackingTarget = transform;

        PlayerActionMap = InputActions.FindActionMap("Player");
        Movement = PlayerActionMap.FindAction("Move");

        Movement.Enable();
        PlayerActionMap.Enable();
        InputActions.Enable();
    }

    public override void OnStopNetwork()
    {
        TimeManager.OnTick -= TimeManager_OnTick;
    }

    private void TimeManager_OnTick()
    {
        RunInputs(CreateReplicateData());
        CreateReconcile();
    }

    private ReplicateData CreateReplicateData()
    {
        if (!IsOwner) return default;

        Vector2 input = Movement.ReadValue<Vector2>();

        if (input == Vector2.zero) return default;

        return new ReplicateData(input.x, input.y);
    }

    [Replicate]
    private void RunInputs(ReplicateData replicateData, ReplicateState replicateState = ReplicateState.Invalid, Channel channel = Channel.Unreliable)
    {
        Vector3 MovementVector = new Vector3(replicateData.horizontal, 0f, replicateData.vertical).normalized;

        if (MovementVector == Vector3.zero) {
            Animator.SetBool("Running", false);
            return;
        }

        if (MovementVector != LastDirection) {
            LerpTime = 0;
        }
        LastDirection = MovementVector;
        TargetDirection = Vector3.Lerp(TargetDirection, MovementVector, Mathf.Clamp01(LerpTime * TargetLerpSpeed * (1 - Smoothing)));

        Debug.Log($"Agent move: {TargetDirection * Agent.speed * (float)TimeManager.TickDelta}");
        Agent.Move(TargetDirection * Agent.speed * (float)TimeManager.TickDelta);
        Debug.Log("AGENT MOVED");
        Vector3 lookDirection = MovementVector;
        if (lookDirection != Vector3.zero) {
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(lookDirection), Mathf.Clamp01(LerpTime * TargetLerpSpeed * (1 - Smoothing)));
        }

        Animator.SetBool("Running", true);

        LerpTime += (float)TimeManager.TickDelta;
    }

    public override void CreateReconcile()
    {
        ReconcileData reconcileData = new(transform.position, transform.rotation, TargetDirection);
        Reconcile(reconcileData);
    }

    [Reconcile]
    private void Reconcile(ReconcileData reconcileData, Channel channel = Channel.Unreliable)
    {
        Debug.Log($"RECONCILE: ({reconcileData.position}) | ({reconcileData.rotation})");
        //Agent.Move(TargetDirection * Agent.speed * (float)TimeManager.TickDelta);
        transform.SetPositionAndRotation(reconcileData.position, reconcileData.rotation);
    }


    private struct ReplicateData : IReplicateData
    {
        private uint tick;
        public readonly float horizontal;
        public readonly float vertical;

        public ReplicateData(float _horizontal, float _vertical)
        {
            tick = 0;
            horizontal = _horizontal;
            vertical = _vertical;
        }

        public readonly uint GetTick() { return tick; }

        public void SetTick(uint _tick)
        {
            tick = _tick;
        }

        public void Dispose() { }
    }

    private struct ReconcileData : IReconcileData
    {
        private uint tick;
        public readonly Vector3 position;
        public readonly Quaternion rotation;
        public readonly Vector3 targetDirection;

        public ReconcileData(Vector3 _position, Quaternion _rotation, Vector3 _targetDirection)
        {
            tick = 0;
            position = _position;
            rotation = _rotation;
            targetDirection = _targetDirection;
        }

        public readonly uint GetTick() { return tick; }

        public void SetTick(uint _tick)
        {
            tick = _tick;
        }

        public void Dispose() { }
    }
}

I pretty much tried everything I found online about Fishnet client prediction and nothing got it to work... What I am expecting is that the inputs are ran on the client and also replicated to the server. Right now they are only replicated to the server apparently...
